# App icon design feedback

Tags: icon, logo, critique

I am designing an app icon for an industry-specific business app that does primarily job management. The name is very likely to be called "JobCheck", which may become a part of a collection, or suite, of apps (ie., FinancialCheck, EquipmentCheck, etc.).

I am aware of the overuse of the checkmark symbol, and would very much like to get away from it. However, with the word "check" as part of the app name, there seems to be this expectation that the checkmark would be part of the icon. It's just very difficult to come up with something unique with it.

I have tried to come up with a few rough ideas and I was wondering if I can get some feedback on them. The company I work for already has its own company logo and colour scheme (orange and grey). I'm trying to go for the "flat" look for I feel like something is missing. Please please let me know how I could possibly improve on them.

[image]

Comment: Note that an app icon typically has the name of the app underneath. As such, you likely don't need text in the icon itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most of the icons you've created are good as a start, but the first thing that came to mind when I saw them was: That's a lot of icons!

I think you are now finding it difficult to choose one among the others because you have created **so many**. Which is not necessarily a bad thing, but **the more you 'expand' on different ideas, the less refined each idea gets.**

I personally like the first one in the second row and the last one (curiously, they don't have checks). I'd try adding a check to the last one instead of the pencil, there's something interesting in the crossing elements.

I'm not convinced with the stripes, the repetition of elements and the check with the missing e because they are simply **difficult to read**. The first one in the top reminds me of a bouncing ball, and the second of a speedometer. I kind of like the speedometer, if you want to go for 'effective, fast' or similar.

But, I'd consider a slightly different process. I'd pick three **concepts**, and try variations from those. For example, your 3 main ideas could be:

- The eye
- The check
- The cloud

Then I'd make 2 designs for each, trying to keep the same concept.

Almost any of the icons you've made can be valid, but I feel they need some more *work*, some *love* ;). The graphics are there, the tick is there, but the concept doesn't feel finished. The most important question here would be: Are you happy with them? Do you have a favorite, one that *talks* to you?

I find [**these sort of articles**](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/logo-design-process-and-walkthrough-for-vivid-ways) very inspiring, because there is so much behind those logos. Logos in general are just fascinating, and while coming up with a nice one is not easy, coming up with a logo that says something about the brand is challenging but rewarding at the same time :)

Comment: Good answer but have to cringe at linking to 99designs. It's not a site we should be linking to.

Comment: @DA01 For people not familiar with 99designs (like me) would you care to add *why* we should not link to them?

Comment: @BartArondson it's what they call a 'logo mill' or 'sweat shop'. A client pays a small fee and hundreds of designers attempt to 'win' the fee by competing. The problem with this model are many, the least of which is that there is no proper professional relationship between the designer and the client. It's essentially spec work and the industry (AIGA, for one) frowns upon spec work for many good reasons: http://www.nospec.com/tag/99designs

Comment: @DA01 The link was to an article about companies doing logos. The original article I liked, I couldn't find, so I just googled a similar one. I didn't know it was spec work, I'll change the link. Spec work = NONONO.

Comment: Link has been changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience of designing thousands of icons Simpler is Better. Yours seem a bit too complex. The orange /grey contrast is also not strong enough for my taste.

Conceptually, here are some ideas that come to mind:
1. The word Job with a check mar inside the O
2. The word Job with a mouse pointer pointing inside the O similar to a radio button
3. Magnifying glass over the word Job
4. The word Job with the O as the lens of the magnifying glass

Hope these help.